# Backing up old directories with a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm writing a small bash script to archive directories off in a compressed format to another location when they are older than a certain age and am having some difficulty. Here's what I'm doing.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Archives completed CDP episodes to compressed storage. Will eventually expand to put these off-site as well.

InputDir="/home/wgant/stuff/"
OutputDir="/home/wgant/archived/"

find $InputDir$ -maxdepth 0 -mtime +1 -type d -exec echo $OutputDir${} \;
```

I'm a little green at bash, so I'm taking it slow. For the first step, I just want to dump a list of what the output files would be called. However, when I run the above, the filenames are right, but the full path is clearly being concatenated in, which I don't want. How do I just strip out the filename?

Obviously once this works, I'll put the calls in to create the tarballs and delete the directory in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is not quite right, this is better:

```
find $InputDir -maxdepth 0 -mtime +1 -type d -exec echo $OutputDir{} \;
```

To strip the prefix part of the paths, an easy way will be to `cd` into the directory before executing the `find`, like this:

```
InputDir="/home/wgant/stuff"
OutputDir="/home/wgant/archived"

(cd "$InputDir"; find . -maxdepth 0 -mtime +1 -type d -exec echo "$OutputDir"/{} \;)
```

---

<sub>Notice that I wrapped the last command within a `(...)`. 
That is a subshell,
the purpose of it is that the `cd` command is only effective inside it,
the rest of the script will not be affected by it.
This is important, because changing the working directory with `cd` is not recommended in scripting. Wrapping it within `(...)` makes it safe.</sub>

Comment: When I tested on the command line, cd'ing into the directory and using the "." instead of the full path still gave me a leading ./ in front of the filename. Is there some way to get rid of that?

Also, is it reasonable when building a shell script to test the individual pieces on the console?

Comment: If you don't have hidden files in that directory, then you can write `find *` instead of `find .` and then you won't have the `./` prefix. If you might have hidden files, let me know.

Comment: Not only it's reasonable to test piece by piece, I recommend it (and do it myself too).

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you! Now I can archive hundreds of gigs of stuff off of my drive!

Comment: Whenever you use `cd` in a script, you should check to make sure it succeeded before continuing with the script, e.g. `cd "$InputDir" || { echo "Error moving to $InputDir; exiting" >&2; exit 1; }`. That way you can avoid having the rest of the script run in an inappropriate and possibly dangerous location (you wouldn't want it archiving off the wrong directory). But there's a trick here: since this section runs in a subshell, the `exit` only exits the subshell, not the main script. So you may have to check the exit status of the subshell, like `(cd ... || { ... exit 1; }; ... ) || exit $?`.